# Given a sorted array (that is sorted in terms of the absolute value) and a number, find the position of the number

Tags: java, arrays

Say we have an array

```
a[] ={1,2,-3,3,-3,-3,4,-4,5}
```

And find the position of 3 (which would be 3)

There are be no multiple indexes for an answer.

It must be efficient, and NOT linear.

I was thinking of doing a Binary Search of the array, but instead of comparing the raw values, I wanted to compare the absolute values; abs(a[i]) and abs(n) [n is the input number]. Then if the values are equal, I do another comparison, now with the raw values a[i] and n.

But I run into a problem where, if I am in the above situation with the same array {1,2,-3,3,-3,-3,4,-4,5}, and am looking for 3, there are multiple -3 that get in the way (thus, I would have to check if the raw values a[i] and n does not work, I have to check a[i+1] and a[i-1].)

Ok im just rambling now. Am i thinking too hard for this?

Help me out thanks!!! :D

Comment: Yes, the binary search finds *an* index in a region with equal values. You can then walk up and down from that index, until you either find the right value or the end of the region. Note that it *has* to be linear in the very worst case - imagine an element with 1000 values of -3 and one value of 3 somewhere in it. They're all equal by absolute value - you can't possibly find the 3 in better than linear time.

Answer (score 3):

It is a modified binary search problem.  The difference between this and regular binary search is that you need to find and test all of the elements that compare as equal according to the sorting criterion.

I would:

- use a tweaked binary search algorithm to find the index of the *left-most* element that matches
- iterate through the indexes until you find the element are looking for, or an element whose absolute value no longer matches.

That should be O(logN) for the first step.  The second step is  O(1) on average if you assume that the element values are evenly distributed.  (The worst case for the second step is O(N); e.g. when the elements all have the same absolute value, and the one you want is the last in the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method to solve your problem:

```
/**
 * @param a array sorted by absolute value
 * @param key value to find (must be positive)
 * @return position of the first occurence of the key or -1 if key not found
 */
public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length-1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int midVal = Math.abs(a[mid]);

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key || (midVal == key && mid > 0 && Math.abs(a[mid-1]) == key))
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -1; // key not found.
}
```

It's a modification of `Arrays.binarySearch` from JDK. There are several changes. First, we compare absolute values. Second, as you want not any key position, but the first one, I modified a condition: if we found a key we check whether the previous array item has the same value. If yes, then we continue search. This way algorithm remains `O(log N)` even for special cases where too many values which are equal to key.